# JQuery ajaxSuccess does not work after upgrading to Rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In `assets/javascripts/user.js.coffee`

```
window.install_loader_image = (elem = 'body') ->
  $(elem).find('.ajax').click ->
    $(this).hide()
    $(this).siblings('.loading').show()
  $(elem).find('.ajax.modal').ajaxSuccess ->
    $(this).show()
    $(this).siblings('.loading').hide()
```

function `install_loader_image()` was called for lines below

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_employee_path(employee), :remote => true, :class => 'ajax modal edit_link'
.loading{:style => 'display: none;'}
  = image_tag 'ajax-loader.gif'
```

Clicking on link calls `edit` action in employees controller

```
def edit
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then `employees/edit.js.erb` file renders and sends to client, and interpreted well in browser. `click` function fires, but `ajaxSuccess` doesn't. While in Rails 3.0 all was working fine.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by changing `ajaxSuccess` to `ajaxComplete` function.